# rule to call another Makefile from inside a Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, compilation

I have a `Makefile` from which I run the command of another `Makefile` if some objects file do not exist already.

The rule is the following:

```
$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.o: $(COMMONDIR)/%.c $(COMMONDIR)/Makefile | $(OBJDIRCOMMON)
    +$(MAKE) -C $(COMMONDIR)
```

where the variables are defined as follows in the same `Makefile`:

```
COMMONDIR     := ../common
SOURCESCOMMON := $(wildcard $(COMMONDIR)/*.c)
OBJDIRCOMMON  := $(COMMONDIR)/obj
OBJECTSCOMMON := $(patsubst $(COMMONDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.o, $(SOURCESCOMMON))
DEPENDSCOMMON := $(patsubst $(COMMONDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.d, $(SOURCESCOMMON))
```

This rule works fine but at the end of the day the only real input required by the rule is the other `Makefile` so I tried:

```
$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.o: $(COMMONDIR)/Makefile | $(OBJDIRCOMMON)
    +$(MAKE) -C $(COMMONDIR)
```

but this does not work, why is that?

For completeness here is the complete `Makefile`

```
CC = gcc

INC_PATH = -I../common/

SOURCEDIR := ./
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)/*.c)
OBJDIR  :=./obj
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
DEPENDS := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.d, $(SOURCES))

COMMONDIR     := ../common
SOURCESCOMMON := $(wildcard $(COMMONDIR)/*.c)
OBJDIRCOMMON  := $(COMMONDIR)/obj
OBJECTSCOMMON := $(patsubst $(COMMONDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.o, $(SOURCESCOMMON))
DEPENDSCOMMON := $(patsubst $(COMMONDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.d, $(SOURCESCOMMON))

# ADD MORE WARNINGS!
WARNING := -Wall -Wextra

# OBJS_LOC is in current working directory,
EXECUTABLE := ../server
# .PHONY means these rules get executed even if
# files of those names exist.
.PHONY: all clean

# The first rule is the default, ie. "make",
# "make all" and "make parking" mean the same
all: $(EXECUTABLE)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(DEPENDS) $(EXECUTABLE)

# Linking the executable from the object files
# $^   # "src.c src.h" (all prerequisites)
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) $(OBJECTSCOMMON)
    $(CC) $(WARNING) $^ -o $@

-include $(DEPENDS) $(DEPENDSCOMMON)

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c Makefile | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(WARNING) -MMD -MP -c $(INC_PATH) $< -o $@

$(OBJDIRCOMMON):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIRCOMMON)

$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.o: $(COMMONDIR)/%.c $(COMMONDIR)/Makefile | $(OBJDIRCOMMON)
    +$(MAKE) -C $(COMMONDIR)
```

**EDIT**

The error I get is like this:

```
Entering directory '/home/user/Documents/UnixSystem/network/common'
gcc -Wall -Wextra -MMD -MP -c utilities.c -o obj/utilities.o
gcc -Wall -Wextra -MMD -MP -c error.c -o obj/error.o
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Documents/UnixSystem/network/common'
gcc   ../common/obj/error.d.o   -o ../common/obj/error.d
gcc: error: ../common/obj/error.d.o: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

From which I understand the execution of the other `Makefile` was successful. However after that it is trying to execute this command `gcc   ../common/obj/error.d.o   -o ../common/obj/error.d`  which is wrong but I do not know which rule and why it's generating it.

Comment: To be complete, please explain what you mean by *...this does not work*.

Comment: see the **EDIT**

Comment: Use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) with `-x` to debug such issues

Comment: I suggest you to use this for your project: https://github.com/igagis/prorab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why what you did was wrong**

Recipe **A**:

```
$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.o: $(COMMONDIR)/%.c $(COMMONDIR)/Makefile | $(OBJDIRCOMMON)
    +$(MAKE) -C $(COMMONDIR)
```

and recipe **B**:

```
$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.o: $(COMMONDIR)/Makefile | $(OBJDIRCOMMON)
    +$(MAKE) -C $(COMMONDIR)
```

have essentially different meanings and will certainly not yield the same behaviour.

Recipe **A** says:

1. Any target `$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/file.o` must be made up-to-date if does not exist
   or is older than either `$(COMMONDIR)/file.c` or `$(COMMONDIR)/Makefile`.
2. If a target `$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/file.o` must be made up-to-date, then `$(OBJDIRCOMMON)`
   must be made up-to-date first.
3. To make a target `$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/file.o` up-to-date, run the expansion of `$(MAKE) -C $(COMMONDIR)` in a shell.

Recipe **B** says:

1. Any target `$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/file.o` must be made up-to-date if does not exist
   or is older than `$(COMMONDIR)/Makefile`.
2. If a target `$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/file.o` must be made up-to-date, then `$(OBJDIRCOMMON)`
   must be made up-to-date first.
3. To make a target `$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/file.o` up-to-date, execute the expansion of `$(MAKE) -C $(COMMONDIR)` in a shell.

Notice that criterion **A.1** is different from criterion **B.1**. Recipe **A** will execute
if `$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/file.o` is older than `$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/file.c`. Recipe **B** will not.
Recipe **B** discards the dependency of the object files on the corresponding source files,
and tells Make that `$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/file.o` is only ever to be remade if it
is older than `$(COMMONDIR)/Makefile`.

> at the end of the day the only real input required by the rule is the other Makefile

What you mean by "the rule" here is actually the commandline (expanded from) `$(MAKE) -C $(COMMONDIR)`.
The inputs of this command are one thing; the criteria for executing it are another.

**How what you did caused the error you see**.

This is thornier. Let's reproduce it.

Here's a playpen:

```
$ ls -R
.:
app  common

./app:
foo.c  main.c  Makefile

./common:
bar.c  Makefile
```

Here, `./app/Makefile` is exactly your Makefile with recipe **A**. `./common/Makefile`,
which you didn't post, is just:

```
obj/bar.o: bar.c
    gcc -MMD -MP -c -I. $< -o $@
```

because that will do for illustration.

We build in `./app`:

```
$ cd app
$ make
mkdir -p ./obj
gcc -Wall -Wextra -MMD -MP -c -I../common/ foo.c -o obj/foo.o
gcc -Wall -Wextra -MMD -MP -c -I../common/ main.c -o obj/main.o
mkdir -p ../common/obj
make -C ../common
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/imk/develop/so/make_prob/common'
gcc -MMD -MP -c -I. bar.c -o obj/bar.o
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/imk/develop/so/make_prob/common'
gcc -Wall -Wextra obj/foo.o obj/main.o ../common/obj/bar.o -o ../server
```

which is fine.

Now I change `./app/Makefile` as you did, to use recipe **B**, and rebuild.

```
$ make
gcc -Wall -Wextra -MMD -MP -c -I../common/ foo.c -o obj/foo.o
gcc -Wall -Wextra -MMD -MP -c -I../common/ main.c -o obj/main.o
gcc -Wall -Wextra obj/foo.o obj/main.o ../common/obj/bar.o -o ../server
```

Still fine... But wait a minute! That one didn't invoke the `./common` make
at all, which is the one that the change might affect. Better `clean`:

```
$ make clean
rm -f ./obj/foo.o ./obj/main.o ./obj/foo.d ./obj/main.d ../server
```

and try again:

```
$ make
gcc -Wall -Wextra -MMD -MP -c -I../common/ foo.c -o obj/foo.o
gcc -Wall -Wextra -MMD -MP -c -I../common/ main.c -o obj/main.o
gcc -Wall -Wextra obj/foo.o obj/main.o ../common/obj/bar.o -o ../server
```

No difference? Ah, that's because this Makefile's `clean` fails to delete all
the files that `make` builds: it leaves out `../common/obj/bar.o`. So I'll just:

```
$ rm ../common/obj/*
```

And have another go:

```
$ make
make -C ../common
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/imk/develop/so/make_prob/common'
gcc -MMD -MP -c -I. bar.c -o obj/bar.o
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/imk/develop/so/make_prob/common'
gcc   ../common/obj/bar.d.o   -o ../common/obj/bar.d
gcc: error: ../common/obj/bar.d.o: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

which is your mystery.

When I zapped the `../common/obj` files, I deleted not only all the *object* files therein
but also the dependency file `../common/obj/bar.d`. And now Make is trying to remake it by running:

```
gcc   ../common/obj/bar.d.o   -o ../common/obj/bar.d
```

How come? To answer that, we'll first change `./app/Makefile` back to use recipe **A**
 - consider it done - and then do:

```
$ make --print-data-base > out.txt
```

which dumps in `out.txt` all the information that Make gleans from reading all
the makefiles (`Makefile` and all the makefiles that it recursively `include`-s,
in this case just the auto-generated `.d` files).

Let's see what the database has to say about `../common/obj/bar.d`. It says:

```
# Not a target:
../common/obj/bar.d:
# Implicit rule search has been done.
# Last modified 2019-01-11 16:01:33.199263608
# File has been updated.
# Successfully updated.
```

Certainly we don't *want* `../common/obj/bar.d` to be a target, and it *isn't* a
target because, having read all the makefiles, and considered all its builtin rules,
and all of the files it can actually find, Make can't see any way in which `../common/obj/bar.d`
has to be made up-to-date with respect to any of those files. Good.

Now let's revert to recipe **B** in `./app/Makefile` again - consider it done -
and again do:

```
$ make --print-data-base > out.txt
```

and again look in `out.txt` concerning `../common/obj/bar.d`. This time we find:

```
../common/obj/bar.d: ../common/obj/bar.d.o
# Implicit rule search has been done.
#  Implicit/static pattern stem: '../common/obj/bar.d'
# Last modified 2019-01-11 16:01:33.199263608
# File has been updated.
# Successfully updated.
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
    $(LINK.o) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

So this time `../common/obj/bar.d` *is* a target! And it depends on `../common/obj/bar.d.o`!
And the recipe to make it is:

```
    $(LINK.o) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

which will expand, of course, to:

```
gcc   ../common/obj/bar.d.o   -o ../common/obj/bar.d
```

How was Make able to work that out, thanks to recipe **B**?

Well first it considered whether any of the rules in the makefiles or any of the
builtin rules gave it direct way to make `../common/obj/bar.d` from any existing files,
and drew a blank.

*Next* it considered whether any of those rules gave it a way to
make `../common/obj/bar.d` from an [*intermediate file*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html). An *intermediate file* being a file that doesn't exist but itself *can* be made
from existing files, by any of the rules it has read or its builtin-rules. This
time it saw a way.

One of Make's builtin pattern rules is:

```
%: %.o
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
    $(LINK.o) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

You can find it in right there in `out.txt`. And you can see this is the pattern rule that
it matches with:

```
../common/obj/bar.d: ../common/obj/bar.d.o
```

The recipe there is a recipe to *link a program* called `../common/obj/bar.d` given
an object file `../common/obj/bar.d.o`.

There is no object file `../common/obj/bar.d.o`, but can it be an intermediate file? If
Make can find a rule for making `../common/obj/bar.d.o` from files that *do* exist,
then it can also make `../common/obj/bar.d` with this `%: %.o` rule.

And it *can* find a recipe for making `../common/obj/bar.d.o` from existing files
because we just gave it one! - recipe **B**:

```
$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.o: $(COMMONDIR)/Makefile | $(OBJDIRCOMMON)
    +$(MAKE) -C $(COMMONDIR)
```

That tells Make that if any target matching `$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.o` (like `../common/obj/bar.d.o`)
does not exist, but `$(COMMONDIR)/Makefile` does exist (which it does), then that target
is made up-to-date by running:

```
$(MAKE) -C $(COMMONDIR)
```

Make believed us. It ran `$(MAKE) -C $(COMMONDIR)`:

```
make -C ../common
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/imk/develop/so/make_prob/common'
gcc -MMD -MP -c -I. bar.c -o obj/bar.o
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/imk/develop/so/make_prob/common'
```

and then considered `../common/obj/bar.d.o` up-to-date. So it moved on to:

```
../common/obj/bar.d: ../common/obj/bar.d.o
    $(LINK.o) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

and ran:

```
gcc   ../common/obj/bar.d.o   -o ../common/obj/bar.d
```

which failed because we lied:

```
make -C ../common
```

does *not* make `../common/obj/bar.d.o` at all.

```
gcc: error: ../common/obj/bar.d.o: No such file or directory
```

This does not arise with recipe **A**, because

```
$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/bar.d.o: $(OBJDIRCOMMON)/bar.d.c $(COMMONDIR)/Makefile | $(OBJDIRCOMMON)
    +$(MAKE) -C $(COMMONDIR)
```

does *not* offer Make a way to make `$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/bar.d.o` from existing files,
because `$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/bar.d.c` does not exist. So `../common/obj/bar.d` is not
a target.

Stick with recipe **A**, because it's right, and recipe **B** is wrong. Also review
and fix the makefiles so that `make clean` always deletes all the non-`.PHONY` targets that might have been built, and nothing else. Lastly avoid writing recipes with non-`.PHONY` targets where the recipe does not  mention the target.

Answer (score 0):

Should there be && instead of pipe

```
      $(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.o: $(COMMONDIR)/Makefile | (OBJDIRCOMMON)
+$(MAKE) -C $(COMMONDIR
```

Comment: You mean `| (OBJDIRCOMMON)`? I don't think so take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52643785/makefile-rule-to-regenerate-object-files-directory-without-recompiling-from-sc

Comment: It's not a pipe; this is not a shell-script. It's an [order-only prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html)