# How to avoid forgetting dependencies in make/CMake?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I am new to C++ and am trying to get the hang of build systems like make/CMake. Coming from Go, it seems that there is a constant risk that if you forget to do a little thing, your binaries will become stale. In particular, I can't find a best practice for remembering to keep dependencies/prerequisites updated in make/CMake. I'm hoping I am missing something obvious.

For example, suppose I have a basic makefile that just compiles `main.cpp`:

```
CFLAGS = -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++17

main: main.o
    clang++ $(CFLAGS) main.o -o main

main.o: main.cpp
    clang++ $(CFLAGS) -c main.cpp -o main.o
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, world\n";
}
```

So far so good; `make` works as expected. But suppose I have some other header-only library called `cow.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace cow {
    void moo() {
        std::cout << "Moo!\n";
    }
}
```

And I decide to call `moo()` from within `main.cpp` via `include "cow.cpp":

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cow.cpp"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, world\n";
    cow::moo();
}
```

However, I forget to update the dependencies for `main.o` in `makefile`. This mistake is not revealed during the obvious testing period of running `make` and rerunning the binary `./main`, because the whole `cow.cpp` library is directly `include`d in `main.cpp`. So everything seems fine, and `Moo!` is printed out as expected.

But when I change `cow.cpp` to print `Bark!` instead of `Moo!`, then running `make` doesn't do anything and now my `./main` binary is out of date, and `Moo!` is still printed from `./main`.

I'm very curious to hear how experienced C++ devs avoid this problem with much more complicated codebases. Perhaps if you force yourself to split every file into a header and an implementation file, you'll at least be able to quickly correct all such errors? This doesn't seem bulletproof either; since header files sometimes contain some inline implementations.

My example uses `make` instead of `CMake`, but it looks like `CMake` has the same dependency listing problem in `target_link_libraries` (though transitivity helps a bit).

As a related question: it seems like the obvious solution is for the build system to just look at the source files and infer dependencies (it can just go one level in and rely on CMake to handle transitivity). Is there a reason this doesn't work? Is there a build system that actually does this, or should I write my own?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Unrelated; You're controlling your builds yourself, but if you use an IDE, odds are good that the IDE will see cow.cpp's cpp extension and decide to compile and link it just like any other cpp file it's given. For this reason, and because people expect cpp files to be compiled and linked, it's best to not use the cpp extension for anything you intend to be included. Use hpp, impl, or something that isn't cpp.

Comment: It is even worse than you think. `make` naively uses file timestamps to figure out whether dependency changed so altering file content without altering timestamp to be newer than dependent code will cause make to do nothing, while bumping timestamp without altering content will cause make to rebuild. So if you are still using `make`-based build system your only choice it to perform `make clean` prior to any build (or manually delete artifacts from previous build), that is to force rebuild.

Comment: At the same time building and processing complete dependency tree of arbitrary project is not trivial and may take longer time than simply building it.

Comment: I can't speak for clang, but in gcc you add on the `-M` compiler switch to produce a dependency file. The makefile uses the dependency file to determine if the source file should be recompiled.

Comment: @drescherjm I haven't actually tried using CMake, I just made this makefile by hand. Does CMake fix the problem I described?

Comment: Yes, CMake tracks dependencies, but I'm not sure it will handle including `.cpp`.

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: To clarify: is it sufficient to change cow.cpp to cow.hpp and switch to CMake to solve this issue?

Comment: Not really. Note that use of cmake typically involves generation of a make file that will be later used to actually build the project.

Comment: [GNU Make: Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/)

Comment: Make and CMake are quite a different things (though CMake is able to produce Make project). Please, leave only one of these tools in the question. As almost whole your post is about Make, I suggest to remove CMake (from the tags and from the question). Otherwise, you have several unrelated questions in your post, but on Stack Overflow we prefer to see **one question per question post**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you will need to reference the dependencies file in your `Makefile`.

This can be done with the function

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard *.cpp)
DEPENDS := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.d,$(SOURCES))
```

wich will take the name of all `*.cpp` files and substitute and append the extension `*.d` to name your dependency.

Then in your code

```
-include $(DEPENDS)
```

`-` tells the `Makefile` to not complain if the files do not exist. If they exist they will be included and recompile your sources properly according to the dependencies.

Finally the dependencies can be created automatically with the options: `-MMD -MP` for the rules to create the objects file. [Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) you can find a complete explanation. What generates the dependencies is `MMD`; `MP` is to avoid some errors. If you want to recompile when system libraries are updated use `MD` instead of `MMD`.

In your case you can try:

```
main.o: main.cpp
    clang++ $(CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -c main.cpp -o main.o
```

If you have more files it is better to have a single rule to create object files. Something like:

```
%.o: %.cpp Makefile 
    clang++ $(CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@
```

You can take a look also at this 2 great answers:

- [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52034997/how-to-make-makefile-recompile-when-a-header-file-is-changed/52036564#52036564)
- [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119783/rule-to-call-another-makefile-from-inside-a-makefile)

In your case a more suitable `Makefile` should look like the following (there might be some errors but let me know):

```
CXX = clang++
CXXFLAGS = -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++17
WARNING := -Wall -Wextra

PROJDIR   := .
SOURCEDIR := $(PROJDIR)/
SOURCES   := $(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)/*.cpp)
OBJDIR    := $(PROJDIR)/

OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SOURCES))
DEPENDS := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.d,$(SOURCES))

# .PHONY means these rules get executed even if
# files of those names exist.
.PHONY: all clean

all: main

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(DEPENDS) main

# Linking the executable from the object files
main: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(WARNING) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@

#include your dependencies
-include $(DEPENDS)

#create OBJDIR if not existin (you should not need this)
$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp Makefile | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CXX) $(WARNING) $(CXXFLAGS) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@
```

**EDIT to answer comments**
*As another question, is there any problem with rewriting the DEPENDS definition as just `DEPENDS := $(wildcard $(OBJDIR)/*.d)`?*

Nice question, it took me a while to see your point

From [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html)

> `$(wildcard pattern…)` This string, used anywhere in a makefile, is
>   replaced by a space-separated list of names of existing files that
>   match one of the given file name patterns. If no existing file name
>   matches a pattern, then that pattern is omitted from the output of the
>   wildcard function.

So `wildcard` return a list of the file names matching the pattern. `patsubst` acts on strings, it does not care about what are those strings: it is used as a way to create the file names of the dependencies, not the files themselves. In the `Makefile` example that I posted `DEPENDS` is actually use in two cases: when cleaning with `make clean` and with `include` so in this case they both work because you are not using `DEPENDS` in any rule. There are some differences (I tried to run and you should too to confirm). With `DEPENDS := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.d,$(SOURCES))` if you run `make clean` dependencies `*.d` that do not have a correspondent `*.cpp` file will not be removed while they will with your change. On the contrary you might include dependencies not relevant to your `*.cpp` file.

I asked [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54196204/1714692): let's see the answers.

*If the `.d` files get deleted from carelessness but the `.o` files remain, then we are in trouble. In the original example, if `main.d` is deleted and then `cow.cpp` is subsequently changed, `make` won't realize it needs to recompile `main.o` and thus it will never recreate the dependency file. Is there a way to cheaply create the `.d` files without recompiling the object files? If so then we could probably recreate all the `/.d` files on every make command?*

Nice question again.

Yes, you are right. Actually it was an error of mine. This happens because of the rule

```
main: main.o
    $(CXX) $(WARNING) $(CFLAGS) main.o -o main
```

actually should have been:

```
main: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(WARNING) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

so that it got relinked (the executable is updated) whenever one of the objects change and they will change whenever one their `cpp` file change.

One problem remains: if you delete your dependencies but not the objects, and change only one or more header files (but not the sources) then your program is not updated.

I corrected also the previous part of the answer.

**EDIT 2**
To create the dependencies you can also add a new rule to your `Makefile`:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2394651/1714692) is an example.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! One corner case: if the `.d` files get deleted from carelessness but the `.o` files remain, then we are in trouble. In the original example, if `main.d` is deleted and then `cow.cpp` is subsequently changed, `make` won't realize it needs to recompile `main.o` and thus it will never recreate the dependency file. Is there a way to cheaply create the `.d` files without recompiling the object files? If so then we could probably recreate all the `/.d` files on every `make` command. But maybe I'm being too paranoid...

Comment: As another question, is there any problem with rewriting the `DEPENDS` definition as just `DEPENDS := $(wildcard $(OBJDIR)/*.d)`?