# Makefile reference dependencies with patsubst or wildcard?

Tags: makefile, dependencies, wildcard

Following this [question and my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54163474/1714692) and its comments I have a doubt.

What is the proper way to reference dependencies in a `Makefile`?

Let me give an example considering this file:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++17
WARNING := -Wall -Wextra

PROJDIR   := .
SOURCEDIR := $(PROJDIR)/
SOURCES   := $(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)/*.cpp)
OBJDIR    := $(PROJDIR)/

OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SOURCES))
DEPENDS := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.d,$(SOURCES))

# .PHONY means these rules get executed even if
# files of those names exist.
.PHONY: all clean

all: main

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(DEPENDS) main

        clean:
            $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(DEPENDS) parking

# Linking the executable from the object files
main: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(WARNING) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@


#include your dependencies
-include $(DEPENDS)

#create OBJDIR if not existin (you should not need this)
$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp Makefile | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CXX) $(WARNING) $(CXXFLAGS) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@
```

I can do `DEPENDS := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.d,$(SOURCES))` but also `DEPENDS := $(wildcard $(OBJDIR)/*.d)`: can't I?

If I delete a source file before running `make clean` the correspondent dependency file remains. In the second case it will be removed with the next `make clean` while in the first it will not. However if I do not run `make clean` dependencies not related to the sources might be included.

What is the best way to reference dependencies in a `Makefile`? Should I use two variables, one to run `clean` and the other for `include`?